# Magento 2 Theme Showing up in DB but not the Admin area options

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database

I have finally been able to install my theme, all the files and the proper commands have all been run. I have tried clearing caches and running the php bin/magento setup:upgrade doesnt help. When I login to the cpanel I see my theme in there and it is set to 0. I have tried everything but when I go to content>design>configuration and select edit on the current theme. My new theme is not listed as an option to select. I have put the store in developer mode as well. Below are my files:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>CyberMark Sparklingearth</title>
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
</media>
</theme>



<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/CyberMark/sparklingearth',
__DIR__
);



{
"name": "magento/theme-frontend-sparklingearth",
"description": "N/A",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6",
    "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.1.*",
    "magento/framework": "100.1.*"
},
"type": "magento2-theme",
"version": "100.1.6",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this "name": "magento/theme-frontend-sparklingearth" line

with "name": "cybermark/sparklingearth" into composer.json

Comment: I did what you suggested. However after applying the following commands

    php bin/magento setup:upgrade –keep-generated
    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
    php bin/magento cache:clean
    php bin/magento cache:flush

It is still not showing up in my dropdown of available choices. I need to get this figured out. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Go into given below link
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-magento-2-theme.html
 and match your theme & folder structure
and if still you are not get solution, then make your vendor name & theme name in small letter.

Comment: I have followed your advice and done these things. Please help its not showing up still.

Comment: please make sure that project deploy mode should be developer mode, clear var/cache, pub/static, var/generation and then deploy the content & check then. If still it's not working, then check your log into exception.log into var/log folder